# Защита кода на странице

Tags: javascript, html, кодировка, защита

Возможно ли защитить исходный код страницы использую только JS?
Например блокировать пункт "Исследовать элемент" и "Исходный код" в меню при нажатии ПКМ, блокировать такие клавиши как <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> и другие, позволяющие просмотреть исходный код.

Comment: Нет, невозможно.

Comment: Никак. Смиритесь с этим.

Comment: Единственное, что может чуть помочь - обфускация кода. Но это просто усложнит отладку, Ваши совершенные алгоритмы всё равно будут доступны.

Comment: нет, спрятать то что закачивается к клиенту в открытом виде невозможно) Единственное что может помочь php))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все указанные вами действия "защитить" нельзя(возможно даже никакие).
Но, даже если бы это и удалось - можно использовать анализаторы трафика(снифферы), при помощи которых можно легко глянуть любой код. Например, *Charles* или *wireshark*.

PS. нужно понимать, что любой html,css,js, который попадает клиенту - нельзя защитить от просмотра, т.к. он должен быть передан по сети и выполнен у клиента, а значит может быть просмотрен не только движком JS, но и человеком:D

PPS. но для защиты кода(js) - можно использовать обфускаторы(заодно они и минификаторы): JSmin, Closure compiler, YUI Compressor.
защитить же css и html - никак нельзя (хотя можно, конечно, его минифицировать, но это в две секунды любой IDE-шкой правится на читабильный вид.)

Comment: Переданное по сети может быть шифром (SSL, например). Другой момент что нельзя шифровать то, что должно быть выполнено у клиента, иначе теряется смысл передачи.