# Есть ли смысл в обфускация html и css?

Tags: html, css

Нарпимер если сделать обфускацию js то есть шанс,найти хороший обфускаторый который на данный момент времени не могут расшифровать.А как быть с html и css можно ли найти такой обфускатор который даст защиту ,что на данный момент времни их не расшифруют?

Comment: Смысла от этого `0`, вы не сможете сделать так, чтобы не расшифровать ничем, как по вашему будет понимать написанное браузер?

Comment: Как-то я задавал от части похожий вопрос - [Защита кода на странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571069/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5), там мне дали простой и чёткий ответ который, как по мне, подходит и к этому вопросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Обфускаторы не шифруют ваш код. Они просто приводят его в неудобочитаемвый вид и малость укорачивают.
2. Вы никак не можете зашифровать переданный клиенту ИНТЕРПРЕТИРУЕМЫЙ код - потому что клиент должен получить его в исходном виде для обработки. Именно в этот момент нехороший человек может открыть полученный файл в чем угодно и ковыряться в коде.
3. Если вы подвергнете код обфускации, вы не защитите его от анализа. Вы просто сделаете этот процесс дольше и получите на свою голову немного проклятий. Обфускация - это как замок на двери, от случайных людей. Профессионала-домушника замок в лучшем случае задержит до приезда полиции.
4. HTML обфусцировать нет смысла - сами по себе элементы ни на что не влияют. Можно усложнить жизнь хакеру, сделав неудобочитаемыми css-классы, но это такое... больше себе навредите, чем ему помешаете.
5. Единственный в данном случае способ дать человеку информацию, но помешать ему ее украсть - написать некую примочку, которая будет обрабатывать предаваемые ей шифрованные данные и показывать их пользователю. Например, какой-нибудь Java- или Flash-апплет, который будет расшифровывать и рендерить ваши данные, не кладя их никуда в открытом виде.
6. Смиритесь.

Comment: Indtagram обфусцирует классы html.

Comment: и что с того?..

Comment: Значит есть какой-то смысл обфусцировать, а то Россграм просто скопировали бы стили

Comment: он бы и так их скопировал. обфускация CSS не сильно поможет против плагиатора, т.к. важны не имена классов, а примененные стили, а их-то браузер как на ладони показывает.

смысл может быть в том, чтобы обломать блокировщики рекламы и контента. Правда, это если генерировать классы динамически, как яндекс, и менять их хотя бы раз в день.